# Disabling controls based on WPF command/command bindings

Tags: wpf, commandbinding

Using commands is handy because WPF automatically disables the source of the command (typically a button) when the command can't be executed.

Evidently, this feature is not available to controls that are not a command source e.g. `ListBox`.

What is the best way to enable this feature for non command source controls. I thought of a couple of solutions:

- Wrap the `ListBox` with a `Button` and change the `ControlTemplate` of the button so that there is no chrome.
- Create an invisible `Button` and bind the `IsEnabled` property of the `ListBox` to the `IsEnabled` property of the `Button`
- Create a descendant of `ListBox` that implements `ICommandSource`.

Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a bool property in your code-behind (or view model) like `CanSelect` or `CanEdit` and bind the `IsEnabled` property of your `ListBox` to it. Just set the value of this new property in the `CanExecute` method of the corresponding command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where does the CanExecute method come from though?

Comment: I'm referring to the ICommand.CanExecute method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute.aspx) that is used by WPF to determine if the command can be executed or not.

Comment: Got it. So who would call ICommand.CanExecute. If the command is attached to a button, WPF does the job (my point #2). Otherwise, how would this work?

Comment: Well, I don't know if you need a Command after all, I thought you already had one and you could just change your new property from there. Maybe you could give us more details and some code about what you want to accomplish...